# Prove that $d(x,y)=\frac{1}{x+y}$ is not a metric space

Tags: metric-spaces

I am supposed to prove that:
$d(x,y)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
0 & x=y \\ 
\frac{1}{x+y} & x\neq y 
\end{matrix}\right.$

is not a metric space, $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{N}$

The first two properties for the metric space holds, also the triangle inequality, if the two elements are equal. But how to prove that it if:

$x\neq y \neq z $, then $d(x,z)\nleqslant d(x,y)+d(y,z)$?

Thank for any help.

Comment: Fortunately, you don't have to prove that $d(x,z)\not\le d(x,y)+d(y,z)$. All you have to do is find one instance where the triangle inequality fails.Maybe you could plug in some numbers at random and try to get lucky? Have you tried that?

Comment: You can't prove that because it's not true in general. You need to find a single _counter-example_: $x,y,z$ such that $d(x,z)\nleqslant d(x,y)+d(y,z)$.

Comment: @bof oh, okay, I thought that I should prove it in general, not just by finding counter exammple. In that way, it is easy :), thank you

Comment: @MartinR: That doesn't work, because $x=z$. But $(x,y,z)=(1,n,2)$ works for any $n\ge 5$.

Comment: @TonyK Why is it a problem that $x=z$ ?

Comment: @TonyK thanks, I thought that I have to prove it in general not just by finding counter example, thanks

Comment: @TonyK: You are right. That is what I *meant* to say.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch: because if $x=z$, then $d(x,z)=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true that $x\neq y\neq z\implies d(x,z)\nleqslant d(x,y)+d(y,z)$ for all $x,y,z\in\mathbb N$, as $x=1,y=2,z=3$ shows. However there are **some** $x,y,z$ such that the triangle inequality doesn't hold.

For example
$$d(1,10)+d(10,5)=\frac{52}{330}<\frac{55}{330}=\frac16=d(1,5).$$

In fact, for distinct $x,y,z$, we have $$d(x,y)+d(y,z)\le d(x,z)$$ if and only if $y^2\geq x^2+x y+ x z+y z+z^2$. So by choosing $y$ large and keeping $x,z$ relatively small, you get counter-examples.

Comment: Thank you for help

Answer (score 3):

Observe that
 $$d(1,2)=\frac{1}{3}$$, 
$$d(1,5)=\frac{1}{6}$$, 
$$d(5,2)=\frac{1}{7}$$

$$d(1,2)=\frac{1}{3}>\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}=d(1,5)+d(5,2)$$.

So the triangle inequality is not satisfied and $d$ is not a metric.

Answer (score 2):

In order to prove that some statement doesn't hold it suffices to find a counterexample. In this case for instance let's consider $x,z$ small, i.e. $x=1$, $z=3$, and $y$ some bigger natural number, such as $y=9$:

$$ d(x,z) = \frac{1}{x+z} = \frac{1}{4}, $$

$$ d(x,y)+d(y,z) = \frac{1}{x+y}+\frac{1}{y+z} = \frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{12} = \frac{11}{60} < \frac{15}{60} = \frac{1}{4} = d(x,z). $$